# What is the cheapest 4k GPU for developer machine

Tags: graphics-cards, pc

My manager bought me a 4k display that is perfectly fine except that I have signifiant laggs on my current i7-7700 integrated GPU, such as delay in displaying input device actions, slowed AERO animations and so on. I'm allowed to perform an upgrade for my current PC (which I give to one of office guys). But here is a question: what GPU should I ask to buy? I mean all papers says that 7700 should handle 4k workload easily (no games or video, just common office work). Is it my hardware problem and I just can buy the same processor which probably doesn't have this issue? Or should I buy some low-end discrete GPU?

I'm good at measuring games performance, I an say which GPU should I buy to achieve some FPS treshold in some game. But I'm powerless in the field of office work because any GPU was able to give reasonable performance on FullHD. But things has changed with 4k arrival.

Comment: How many monitors are you using and what are their resolutions? What ports do you need on the graphics card? I feel pretty confident that any current gen GPU would support a single 4K display, but I am not 100% sure of this.

Comment: Single, but it's possible to have another one in near future. So 4k or 2x4k.